# Get characters after specific substring from string in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to store a specific piece of a string as a variable in Bash.
I have this string:

```
data="
prop1:    v1
prop2:    v2
prop3:    v3
"
```

I use this code to select the v2 from the string:

```
subStr=$(echo "$data" | awk '"prop2:" {print $2}')
```

But the value of subStr is empty...

I tried using grep for searching prop2 and select the following characters but i did not get that working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the first field against `prop2:` at the beginning of string:

```bash
$ subStr=$(awk '$1 ~ /^prop2:/ {print $2}' <<<"$data")
$ echo "$subStr"
v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use with "/":

```
subStr=$(echo "$data" | awk '/prop2:/ {print $2}')
```

Output:

```
echo "$subStr"
v2
```